# How to start immediate = false component?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have following component:

```
@Component(
    label = "Service name",
    description = "Service description",
    metatype = true,
    immediate = false)
@Properties({
    @Property(
            label = "My Label"
            name = "property-name",
            value = "my value",
            propertyPrivate = true
    )
})
@Service
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {
    private final Logger log = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * OSGi Properties *
     */
    private static final String DEFAULT_SAMPLE = "hello!";
    private String mySample = DEFAULT_SAMPLE;
    @Property(label = "Prop name", 
              description = "Prop description", 
              value = DEFAULT_SAMPLE)
    public static final String PROP_SAMPLE = "sample";

    ...

    @Activate
    protected void activate(final Map<String, String> config) { 
        mySample = PropertiesUtil.toString(config.get(PROP_SAMPLE), DEFAULT_SAMPLE);
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate(final Map<String, String> config) { }
}
```

It registered after cq started. It is expected behaviour.

How to start it ? I cannot find this interface.

Comment: What do you mean, "I cannot find this interface"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is expected behaviour for non-immediate components. From [a blog post](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2010/01/dsdelayedcomponent.html) by Felix Meschberger on dev.day.com,

> The OSGi Declarative services specification defines three types of
>   components:
>
> - **Immediate Components** are immediately created when the
>     providing bundle is started and may or may not provide services
> - **Delayed Components** provide services but are only created when used by
>     a service consumer.
> - **Factory Components** are created on demand by
>     calling the ComponentFactory.newInstance(Dictionary) method of the
>     Component Factory service registered for the component.

So, if you set `immediate = false`, you will have a delayed component, which is activated on-demand by the run-time — you do not need to explicitly start the component yourself.

The main thing that you should be checking for is that the component is in a state of "Enabled" or "Registered" (as you mentioned that it is) rather than "Unsatisfied" (where it can't find references to dependencies it needs).

[From the Felix documentation](http://felix.apache.org/apidocs/scr/1.2.0/org/apache/felix/scr/Component.html#STATE_REGISTERED)…

> **STATE_REGISTERED**
>
> The Component has successfully been activated but is a Delayed or Service Factory Component pending instantiation on first use (value is 32).

Comment: can you explain how **activate on-demand by the run-time** ? maybe you can provide code snippets ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, as in, Felix (or whichever container you're using) will look after this for you. Not sure how it's implemented behind the scenes, but you shouldn't need to worry about it — if you've got a reference to a service exposed by this component, the component will be activated automatically when the service is used.

Answer (score -2):

```
@Component( enabled= false,...)
```

and go to `system/console/components`

Comment: @Neil Bartlett I am author of question and this answer relevant for me

Comment: I know you're the author of the question. This answer may satisfy you but you are confused... component enablement and delayed activation are different things.